# Efficient use of line break in shell script

Tags: shell-script

Context: 
*I have a task to run a few script on a remote machine, and exit*

I have a script, but I am confused how to use the line break inside it,

```
triggerPerformanceTest(){
report=$1
userDataFiles=$2
baseURL=$3
cdnURL=$4
streamingURL=$5
echo "Startin the Jmeter script"
ssh -tt -i Test.ppk username@<test server> <<EOF
cd apache-jmeter-3.1/bin/
JVM_ARGS="-Xms512m -Xmx25000m" ./jmeter.sh -n -t /home/ubuntu/JMeter/Test.jmx --jmeterproperty XMLReport=$report --jmeterproperty UserDataFile=$userDataFiles --jmeterproperty BaseUrl=$baseURL --jmeterproperty CdnUrl=$cdnURL --jmeterproperty StreamingUrl=$streamingURL --jmeterproperty isBenchMark=false --jmeterproperty Enable_DigitalExhaust=true --jmeterproperty Enable_Health=true --jmeterproperty HealthPollingInterval=6
exit
EOF
echo "Test successfully executed"
}

triggerPerformanceTest Log.csv UserDataFile.csv localhost localhost localhost
```

In step two, where I am running the JMeter script, it has a lot of properties. Is there a way I can use a line break here, so it will consider all the lines to be in one step. Like mentioned below

```
ssh user@server << EOF
  command_one
  command_two argument1 argument2 argument3 argument4
              argument5 argument6 argument7
  command_three
EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes end lines with a `\` to continue on next line.

```
ssh user@server << EOF
  command_one
  command_two argument1 argument2 argument3 argument4\
              argument5 argument6 argument7
  command_three
EOF
```

Answer (score 8):

Inside here documents where the delimiter after `<<` (here `EOF`) is not quoted, the `<backslash><newline>` sequence is removed, that's a *line continuation*.

Actually, the only cases where `<backslash><newline>` is not removed is:

- inside single quotes
- inside here documents where the delimiter is quoted
- where the backslash itself is quoted (`<backslash><backslash><newline>`)

```
cat << EOF
foo\
bar
EOF
```

outputs

```
foobar
```

So, here you can do:

```
ssh user@server << EOF
  command_one
  command_two argument1 argument2 argument3 argument4 \
              argument5 argument6 argument7
  command_three
EOF
```

And `ssh` will end up being fed:

```
  command_one
  command_two argument1 argument2 argument3 argument4               argument5 argument6 argument7
  command_three
```

On its stdin.

Even if you used: `ssh ... << 'EOF'` so as to avoid parameter expansion, command substitution and arithmetic expansion being performed inside the here-document, `ssh` would be fed:

```
  command_one
  command_two argument1 argument2 argument3 argument4 \
              argument5 argument6 argument7
  command_three
```

But the remote shell would interpret that `<backslash><newline>` as a line continuation, so it would have the same effect.

Note that when you do:

```
ssh user@server << EOF
```

`sshd` on the remote host runs the user's login shell to interpret that code. Since it could be anything, not necessarily a Bourne-like shell, it may be better to run:

```
ssh user@server sh << EOF
```

Where `sshd` runs `user-s-login-shell -c sh`, so you know a Bourne-like shell is interpreting your code.

As an example that `JVM_ARGS="-Xms512m -Xmx25000m" ./jmeter.sh...` is Bourne-shell or compatible syntax. It would work in `csh`, `tcsh`, `rc`, `es`, `fish` shells, so wouldn't work with `ssh user@server sh << EOF` if the login shell of `user` on `server` was one of those shells.

A significant difference though is that in that case, `user-s-login-shell` is not started as a login shell so won't  read `/etc/profile` or `~/.profile` (or the equivalent for the user's login shell) to set the login session up.

Alternatively, you could convert that code to a syntax compatible to all those shells: `env JVM_ARGS='-Xms512m -Xmx25000m' ./jmeter.sh...` (use single quotes instead of double quotes and use `env` to pass an env var instead of the Bourne/rc specific `envvar=value cmd` syntax).

The backslashes can be avoided by using `xargs`:

```
ssh user@server sh << EOF
  command_one
  xargs command_two << END_OF_ARGS
    argument1 argument2 argument3 argument4
    argument5 argument6 argument7
  END_OF_ARGS
  command_three
EOF
```

Or by using a shell like `rc`, `ksh93`, `zsh`, `bash`, `yash` and an array:

With `rc`/`zsh` syntax:

```
ssh user@server zsh << 'EOF'
  command_one
  args=(
    argument1 argument2 argument3 argument4
    argument5 argument6 argument7
  )
  command_two $args
  command_three
EOF
```

(here quoting `EOF` so that `$args` is not expanded by the local shell).

Or with the `ksh93`/`bash`/`yash` syntax (also works with `zsh`):

```
ssh user@server bash << 'EOF'
  command_one
  args=(
    argument1 argument2 argument3 argument4
    argument5 argument6 argument7
  )
  command_two "${args[@]}"
  command_three
EOF
```